# Opening Netbeans terminal on project folder

Tags: netbeans, terminal, netbeans-8

By default when I open the terminal in Netbeans 8, it opens in the home directory. Is there any way to open it as default in the current project directory? What should I change to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to know this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40301/terminalextras

This plugin opens selected dir in the terminal with a shortcut. Not exactly what you want, but still, much easier to navigate to a directory. Works with Netbeans 8 as well.

Comment: Perfectly good plugin to open terminal in desired location within project. Just click on a node and press alt+/

Comment: The suggested "TerminalExtras" plugin is just nice! If you have it installed you can click on every directory in your projects you like and by simply using "Alt" + "." on your keyboard, it opens up the selected directory in the NetBeans terminal. AWESOME!

Comment: Thanks for this hint, saves me hours of "cd .."